# Why the system killed my python program? But I haven't found any log in the var/log directory

Tags: python

I have a python code which is an iteration program. After running the loop for thousands times, it was killed by the system. I tried to find the reason why it was killed. But I did found anything about that.

The terminal output is like the follow:

```
My own output!
Killed     <---- (This line is the system output. Not included in my code)
```

I have used several methods like

```
dmesg | egrep -i B100 'killed process'
```

But I still could not find anything.

I used `top` to monitor the memory usage. It only used about 6GB, but I got 128GB memory.

**Update:**

OS version: Ubuntu 16.04

Others: 
     Python 3.7.6
     Tensorflow-GPU 1.15
     GPU: TITAN Xp, 12GB.
     Training Neural network: 128, 64, two  Fully-connected  layers
     System memory: 128GB.
     Memory my program used: about 6GB.

**About the bugs in the code: I run the program on my macbook pro, it is good. Exit until it finished.**

And when I run the program, no one is using the machine besides me. So it should be killed by the system not other user.

Update: When I use root to run the program, it will not be killed.

Comment: Please include additional information about how the system killed your process. Was there a traceback? What was the error code?

Comment: Just including whatever message led you to believe that the process was "killed by the system" would be an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Your program may have requested memory exceeding what is available for a progress. For a 32-bit OS, a program could only access up to 4 Gb of memory theoretically.

I have not tried running a 64-bit program consuming more than 4 Gb of memory. I am not sure if it could reach 128 Gb limit.

To answer why it has no log, even you have out in exception handling, is because it has run out of memory, not able to create new object to print out the log.

You should re-look at your code if you could de-reference variables regularly so that garbage collection within Python can removed them so that you have more memory.

If you are running on Linux, you use `pmap` to see types of memory usage for specific progress.

You could post some sample code for other to help.

**UPDATE on 28-March-2020**

Depending on the underlying libraries that you would use, some may not handle memory allocation gracefully.  Your OS normally would kill progresses that perform illegal operations, such as assessing memory out of pre-allocated region, etc.

I have written 2 scripts to test huge memory allocation issues under Windows 10 Home with Python 3.7.6

**`stress1.py`: Using `numpy` library**

```
import numpy as np

size = 10_000

a = []

for i in range(size):
    b = np.random.rand(size, size)
    a.append(b)

for i in a:
    print(i)
```

`numpy` displays the cause of the memory error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stress1.py", line 8, in <module>
    b = np.random.rand(size, size)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1156, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.rand
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 421, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.random_sample
  File "_common.pyx", line 256, in numpy.random._common.double_fill
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 763. MiB for an array with shape (10000, 10000) and data type float64
```

**`stress2.py`: Using Python standard library**

```
size = 1_000_000_000

a = []
for _ in range(20):
    b = list(range(size))
    a.append(b)

for i in a:
    print(i)
```

The script displays

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stress3.py", line 6, in <module>
    b = list(range(size))
MemoryError
```

If you could share your code or libraries that you use, I am sure someone in stackoverflow could help.

Comment: Note that questions that don't provide sufficient information to permit concrete, non-speculative answers should generally be closed, not answered. See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the bullet point regarding questions that "are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem".

Comment: This answer's accuracy is also suspect. Requesting memory that isn't available generally results in a failed `malloc()` call. This doesn't prevent a program from checking the call's result and printing or logging an error, or in the case of the Python interpreter throwing an exception (particularly if the failed allocation is much larger than the available memory, in which case space for the much smaller exception will generally be available). Even without the ability to create an exception object, writing a constant message to stderr does not require any new memory allocation at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  When I started to run the program, it will use about 6GB memory, and it runs for about one hour. Then it was killed. For the code, it has about 1000 lines. It shows a text "Killed" on the screen. I don't know why. I think the system must log this operation('kill some job'). But I didn't find anything about that program.

Comment: @dong, any program (running as the same user, or running as root) can send another process a SIGKILL. It's only in the kernel logs when it's the OOM killer that does it. If you want to log signals being sent other ways, look at sysdig or bpftrace.

Comment: If there is a `killed` message, then the program is killed by other process or the OS itself. Care to share your OS, Python version?  Otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: By the way, you mention writing to unallocated memory, but that will cause a SIGSEGV, not a SIGKILL.

Comment: What you said is true.  Wait for his reply. If he does not follow up, I will just delete my answer.

Comment: Python version is 3.7.6. I think there are not writes to unallocated memory. I run the program many times.When it is killed is random. It is very strange.

Comment: In ubuntu, if one program was killed, the system should output some messages in some log files. But I didn't find anything the record that event. Does anyone knows that. My ubuntu version is 16.04.

Comment: You can install `strace` via this command: `sudo apt install strace`. Trace your program by executing `strace python myprogram.py`.  Show us the results